# Python - why isnt my function outputting 'a' ten times? Beginner question

Tags: python, function, for-loop

```
def testfunction():
    for i in range(10):
        return('a')


print(testfunction())
```

I want 'a' outputed 10 times in one line. If I use print instead of return, it gives me 10 'a's but each on a new line. Can you help?

Answer (score 3):

`return` terminates the current function, while print is a call to another function(atleast in python 3)

Any code after a return statement will not be run.
Python's way of printing 10 a's would be:

```
print('a' * 10)
```

In your case it would look like the following:

```
def testfunction ():
    return 'a' * 10

print(testfunction ())
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason its only printing once is because the return statment finishes the function (the return function stops the loop).

In order to print 'a' 10 times you want to do the following:

```
def testfunction():
    for i in range(10):
        print('a')


testfunction()
```

Comment: got it. but this will also print "None". I think you can put return('a'*10)

Comment: You could as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want "a" printed 10 times in one single line then you can simply go for:

```
def TestCode():
       print("a"*10)
```

There's no need to use the for loop. For loop will just "a" for 10 times but every time it'll be a new line.

You can also take in a function argument and get "a" printed as many times as desired.
Such as:

```
def TestCode(times):
       t = "a"*times
       print(t)
```

Test:

```
TestCode(5)
>>> aaaaa

TestCode(7)
>>> aaaaaaa
```

Answer (score 0):

`print` and `return` get mixed up when starting Python.

A function can `return` anything but it doesn't mean that the value will be `printed` for you to see.  A function can even return another function (it's called functional programming).

The function below is adapted from your question and it `returns` a string object.  When you `call` the function, it `returns` the `string` object into the variable called `x`.  That contains all of the info you wanted and you can `print` that to the console.

You could have also used `yield` or `print` in your for loop but that may be outside of the scope.

```
def test_function(item:str="a", n:int=10):
    line = item*n # this will be a string object
    return line

ten_a_letters = test_function()
print(ten_a_letters)
"aaaaaaaaaa"

two_b_letters = test_function("b",2)
print(two_b_letters)
"bb"
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want 'a' outputed 10 times in one line. If I use print instead of
>   return, it gives me 10 'a's but each on a new line.

If you want to use `print`, the you need to pass a 2nd parameter as follows:

```
def testfunction():
    for i in range(10):
        print('a', end='')
```

However, I think the pythonic way would be to do the following:

```
def testfunction():
    print('a' * 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `return` you end the execution of the function immediately and only one value is returned.
Other answers here provide an easier way to solve your problem (which is great), but I would like to suggest a different approach using `yield` (instead of `return`) and create a **generator** (which might be an overkill but a valid alternative nonetheless):

```
def testfunction():
    for i in range(10):
        yield('a')

print(''.join(x for x in testfunction()))
```

---

<sup>1. [What does "yield" keyword do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/231767/1918287)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
def test ():
    print('a' * 10)

test()
```

Output will be 'aaaaaaaaaa'.